# Difference between Apple TLS with Objective-C and Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsstream, cfnetwork

I am using Apple's CFNetworking to get a TLS stream. I'm having a bit of trouble porting over the Objective-C code to Swift.

With the exact same steps, it works when using Objective-C, but the handshake consistently fails when attempting with Swift.

Working Obj-c

```
- (void)connect()
{
    CFReadStreamRef readStream;
    CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       (__bridge CFStringRef)hostAddress,
                                       port,
                                       &readStream,
                                       &writeStream);

    self.inputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSInputStream *)readStream;
    self.outputStream = (__bridge_transfer NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

    [self.inputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                      forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];
    [self.outputStream setProperty:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL
                       forKey:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey];

    [self.inputStream setDelegate:self];
    [self.outputStream setDelegate:self];

    [self.inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [self.outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]
                                 forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    [self.inputStream open];
    [self.outputStream open];
}
```

Non-working Swift

```
func connect() {
    var readStream: Unmanaged<CFReadStream>?
    var writeStream: Unmanaged<CFWriteStream>?

    let host = "some_host"
    let hostAsCFString = host as NSString
    CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                       hostAsCFString,
                                       1337,
                                       &readStream,
                                       &writeStream)

    inputStream = readStream!.takeRetainedValue()
    outputStream = writeStream!.takeRetainedValue()

    inputStream!.delegate = self
    outputStream!.delegate = self

    inputStream!.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL,
                             forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)
    outputStream!.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL,
                              forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)

    inputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    outputStream!.scheduleInRunLoop(.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    inputStream!.open()
    outputStream!.open()
}
```

Both are attempting to connect to the same server and same port.

Screen grabs of wireshark:

Working Obj-C

[image: Working Wireshark screen grab]

Non-working Swift

[image: Non working Wireshark screen grab]

I'm pretty clueless as to what is going on. I have no idea why the Obj-C version starts a Client Hello with TLS v1.2, but Swift tries with TLS v1.0, then just gives up. No idea why the Swift version takes so long to send the Client Hello, a Keepalive packet is sent prior?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might not change anything, but the order in which you set NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL and the delegate is swapped between your ObjC and Swift versions.

Comment: That doesn't matter. The handshake does not start until the first read or write call on either end of the stream.

Comment: What about the context in which this `connect()` method is called? Is it on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, both are on the main thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there was no difference, I was just an idiot. I was immediately calling `outputStream.write()` once the `NSStreamEvent.OpenCompleted` event had be called for both input and output streams. Which was writing into the buffer of the SSL Handshake, and messing it all up.

Not found until I created a MVP for both Obj-c and Swift, which just goes to show that if you take the time to create a valid MVP, you'll probably figure it out while writing it. Now, if I can only find a way to be notified once the handshake is completed, this problem will always be avoided.